# Setup and partitioning of Ubuntu/Windows 10 dual boot on my new desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, ssd

I am setting up my new desktop as primarily linux (for now I am starting with Ubuntu) and keep a Windows 10 system for config of hardware.

After reading about the different linux distros, there are so many and I dont know which to try. But to make it easier in the future I want to effectively partition my ssds to make it easier to change distro or reset system in the future.

I have 3 ssds:

```
nvme_0- 500gb nvme ssd

nvme_1- 500gb nvme ssd

ssd_0- 250gb ssd
```

I thought it would be best to partition the root drive (/) and the home drive (/home) in nvme_0 and nvme_1 respectively. I would also need an efi and swap partition so i put 250mb for efi in ssd_0, 65536mb for swap area in ssd_0 and then the rest of ssd_0 will be the windows 10 system.

Is this a good and robust setup for me to keep the windows 10 system and easily boot to it no matter changing the linux system if needed?

If there is a better solution please feel free to let me know.

thanks for your assistance community

Comment: I like to keep operating systems in smaller / (root) partitions and have a large shared data partition. I do not share /home so keep it and then only its mostly hidden user configuration files in same partition as /.  I used to do that with Windows, but newer Windows makes it more difficult. With your RAM, you may nto use swap and you actually do not want to use swap as it is orders of magnitude slower than RAM. Do not confuse /boot with ESP - efi system partition (which does have some boot files). Best not to have separate /boot unless more like a server configuration or LVM with encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here but I may have some input.

I would personally make the EFI partition 550MB. Obviously you need to install Windows 10 first, then your favorite Linux distro (Debian in my case) as follows:

You need a /boot / (root) and Swap partition, depending on your hardware. You can optionally have your /home on its own partition but to keep things simple I'd leave root and home on the same partition and have your /boot separate to your Windows EFI boot partition (easier to troubleshoot if anything bad happens).

You'll need to choose a file system for your root partition. Ext4 is solid as hell but you can can go with the new Btrfs (Butter FS) or experiment with ZFS (Offers better protection against data corruption).

If your computer has a lot of RAM then you can even skip using a swap partition or reduce its usage once Linux is installed with something called "Swappiness".

Having Windows on your first SSD and Linux on the second will let you mess up as many Linux installations as you like without harming your data on Windows 10. Just remember that once you install a Linux distro, you will be overriding the Windows boot manager with GRUB (The Linux boot loader).

Hopefully some of this made sense.

All the best.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin.

May is ask why 550mb specifically for efi?

I went with ext4.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin.

May is ask why 550mb specifically for efi?

I went with ext4.

In regards to root and home, I do machine learning and object detection. So storage is important aswell. I thought about keeping root and home in the same, but then they would have to share 500gb. This way I can still move data in and out of home drive with each having 500gb. Although I did just start reading about Raid 0 for my two 500gb nvme drives. perhaps that is worth a shot.

I currently have 32gb of ram and will soon be upgrading to 64gb, hence which i went with the double swap area.

Comment: 512 or 550 is the recommended size for what you want to do. Reason being, you can always make the EFI smaller, you can't make it larger and you don't know what kind of firmware updates you will need in future so that's why 550 is used.

Ext4 is a great choice. Can't go wrong. I was going to suggest you do Raid 0 but I think it might be too much for your first dual boot install. Plus your SSDs are NVMe which is fast enough.

If you're doing machine learning then you'll want a good GPU as the neural networks (NNs) are done with a fast GPU as it would take way longer to use the CPUs.

Comment: Ran out of space.. continuing.. If you want another trick, look up tmpfs where you can create a storage space using your RAM. You will go from your regular SSD transfer rates of 500MB/sec or in your case up to 3GB/sec to what your RAM can handle which is over 20GB/sec if you have DDR4. I use it a lot to build worldlists. It does them instantly.